# how to split a tableview cell into two?

Tags: iphone

I like to create a cell like contacts's add instant messages table view, with two cells to select: "AIM" and "home".

May be I can use the custom table cell as the cell's content view, but the table view framework always treats 
one table view' cell as a whole, for example ,how to respond to did select row at index path message?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that Contacts is using a single cell.

The illusion of two cells is created by a custom cell that contains two buttons each configured to look like a tableveiw cell.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same effect as Tweetie's split cell, create a custom cell and add a Segmented Control and create title and detail labels[image]